# socket.Io issue in newer version

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm following this old [guide](http://www.doc-developpement-durable.org/file/Projets-informatiques/cours-&-manuels-informatiques/Web/Socket.IO%20Real-time%20Web%20Application%20Development.pdf) and try to convert it to newer version of socket.io

My issue is that this code
`var myNamespace = self.namespace.connected[socket.id];`
dosen't work in newer versions.

I believe that it is the `[socket.id]` that has been changed in newer versions.

I saw this post and the last comment has the same problem as I but no solutions.
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
var myNamespace = self.namespace.connected['/name_space#' +socket.client.id];
```